# Jquery Dialog Close doesn't work

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have 2 simple pages.

Index contains a hyperlink with an anchor tag which with jquery has a function click defined.
The page also contains a DIV called "container"

The click function opens a dailog using .dialog()

The dialog page itself is a second page in which i try to close the dialog but this doesnt work.

Can you explain me why this is not working?

====== CODE FROM INDEX PAGE ===========

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $("#LaunchModal").click(function () {
            $.get(
                "Home/RandomPopupView",
                function (htmlResult) {
                    $("#RandomModal").remove(); //In case this is the second time they've requested the dialog.
                    $("#container").append(htmlResult);
                    $("#RandomModal").dialog();
                }
            );
            return false; //To keep the default behavior of the anchor tag from occuring.
        });
    });
</script>
<a href="" id="LaunchModal">Launch Modal!</a>
<div id="container">
```

====== CODE FROM DIALOG PAGE ===========

```
<div id="RandomModal">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {

            //TEST TRY TO CLOSE THE DIALOG DIV IMMEDIATELY FROM WITHINN THE DIV ITSELF
            $("#RandomModal").dialog("close"); //CLOSE DOES NOT WORK

            $("#submitModal").click(function () {
                var SomeString = $("#SomeString").val()

                $.post("/Home/RandomPopupViewPOST",
                {
                    SomeString: SomeString
                },
                    function (html) {
                        $("#RandomModal").empty();
                        $("#RandomModal").append(html);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

=======================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the get method doesn't load a page you would need to load iframe to get ready event on second page to trigger

so I would us  put your code in the main page and use live event

```
$("#submitModal").live("click",function () {
    var SomeString = $("#SomeString").val()

    $.post("/Home/RandomPopupViewPOST",
    {
        SomeString: SomeString
    },
        function (html) {
            $("#RandomModal").empty();
            $("#RandomModal").append(html);
        });
});
```

though I'm not sure thats the right solution either the more i read your code the more I don't understand what your trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load and execute additional script, you should use `$.getScript()`.

See the documentation for it on jQuery's website to get a better idea of how to use it: [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the `$("#RandomModal").dialog("close");` code on the index page.